# Sending contents of a particular div on page with "Send page by e-mail" option of IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media

I have a page with a div hidden that has some contents in it.
I want to able to send only the contents of this hidden div and nothing else on the page with "send page by e-mail" option if IE.
How can I do this? 
Is there any specific css support for this purpose like we have print media type for printing 
documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Send -> Page By Email" seems to copy over all page content into a new email window. The CSS doesn't seem to stick, but the table structures do (in an Outlook email at least). This might be because Outlook can't handle css layouts. I haven't done any HTML email lately (thank god) but from what I remember, you couldn't count on CSS for laying out HTML emails, especially for the MS-based email clients.

What this tells me is that this is NOT a 'version' of the page the way that the screen vs print versions of the page are rendered in the browser with applied CSS. When the email loads from that command, it grabs ALL content on the page, even stuff that's hidden via CSS by default. My feeling is that its grabbing the HTML and pasting it directly into the email, along with the embedded images.

Final conclusion: **Standard media directives for CSS will be useless for this scenario.**

Your best bet would be to prepare an alternate version of the page (with ONLY the desired elements present in the HTML source), which uses tables for rough page layout. Have the users click to this page, and THEN instruct them to use the "Send -> Page by Email" command.

Comment: Thanks Graham....So this means i wont be able to manipulate or change contents captured by the email command right using javascript or css?

Comment: My first instinct is NO, sadly, unless you want to explore the deep, dark world of IE ActiveX controls. You could theoretically check that out, but I have no experience in it. Google searches for hijacking Send Page By Email seems to yield no advice at all, so I'm thinking everything here is a dead end. And rightfully so, a webpage shouldn't be able to totally hijack any browser function it wants.

Comment: Now I have created a separate page for the contents but when i use send page bye e-mail, it shows  characters like ਍਍ℼ佄呃偙⁅瑨汭倠䉕䥌⁃ⴢ⼯㍗⽃䐯䑔堠呈䱍ㄠ..Where am i going wrong here?

Comment: Probably the site is using a character encoding that the email app can't handle maybe?